# DacFx regression error v14 vs v15. Version 15 is issuing "ALTER DATABASE" statements at DacServices.Deploy() time, but it should not

Tags: c#, sql-server, dacpac, dac

I'm using the DACFx DLLs in a web project that can generate a dacpac and restore it somewhere else (new empty database in another server and perhaps a different SQL Server version).

A backup created via DacServices.Extract() with version 14 (e.g. 14.0.3917.1) or version 15 (e.g. 15.0.5084.2) can be restored via DacServices.Deploy() without any issues.

The exact same code (c# .csproj) referencing 15.0.5084.2 instead of 14.0.3917.1 at restore time fail with errors similar to this:

```
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5170, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot create file 'X:\SQLServer\DATA\olddb.ldf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script: ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] ADD LOG FILE (NAME = [dnn9me_log], FILENAME = 'X:\SQLServer\DATA\olddb.ldf', SIZE = 2880 KB, MAXSIZE = 2097152 MB, FILEGROWTH = 10 %);
```

The results are the same running Extract() and Deploy() on a SQL Server 2014 or later database (e.g. 2019).
I mean, a standard simple database NOT on Azure.

I'm using the following options to perform the Extract():

```
DacExtractOptions = 
{
ExtractAllTableData = true, 
IgnorePermissions = true, 
IgnoreUserLoginMappings = true, 
ExtractUsageProperties = false,
IgnoreExtendedProperties = false,
ExtractReferencedServerScopedElements = false, 
ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly = false,
}
```

And I'm using the following options to perform the Deploy():

```
excludeObjectTypes = ServerAuditSpecifications, ServerRoleMembership, ServerRoles, 
ServerTriggers, LinkedServers, Filegroups,Logins, Users, Assemblies, AssemblyFiles, 
ApplicationRoles, Permissions, RoleMembership, DatabaseOptions, DatabaseRoles, 
DatabaseTriggers, PartitionSchemes, ExtendedProperties, Tables, Views, UserDefinedDataTypes, 
UserDefinedTableTypes, ScalarValuedFunctions, TableValuedFunctions, PartitionFunctions,
StoredProcedures, XmlSchemaCollections

doNotDropObjectTypes =  ServerAuditSpecifications, ServerRoleMembership, ServerRoles, 
ServerTriggers, LinkedServerLogins, LinkedServers, Filegroups, Logins, Users, Assemblies, 
AssemblyFiles, ApplicationRoles, Permissions, RoleMembership, DatabaseOptions, DatabaseRoles, 
DatabaseTriggers, PartitionSchemes, ExtendedProperties, Tables, Views, UserDefinedDataTypes, 
UserDefinedTableTypes, ScalarValuedFunctions, TableValuedFunctions, PartitionFunctions, 
StoredProcedures, XmlSchemaCollections


DacDeployOptions = 
{
IgnorePermissions = true,
IgnoreUserSettingsObjects =  true,
IgnoreLoginSids = true, 
IgnoreRoleMembership =  false,
DoNotDropObjectTypes = doNotDropObjectTypes.ToArray(),
ExcludeObjectTypes = excludeObjectTypes.ToArray(),
AllowDropBlockingAssemblies = false,
AllowIncompatiblePlatform = true, 
AllowUnsafeRowLevelSecurityDataMovement = false, 
BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges = false, 
BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = true, 
BlockWhenDriftDetected = true, 
CommentOutSetVarDeclarations = false, 
CompareUsingTargetCollation = false, 
CreateNewDatabase = false, 
DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode = false, 
DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers = true, 
DoNotAlterChangeDataCaptureObjects = true, 
DoNotAlterReplicatedObjects = true, 
RegisterDataTierApplication = false, 
DropConstraintsNotInSource = true, 
DropDmlTriggersNotInSource = true, 
DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource = true, 
DropIndexesNotInSource = true, 
DropObjectsNotInSource = false, 
DropPermissionsNotInSource = false, 
DropRoleMembersNotInSource = false, 
DropStatisticsNotInSource = false, 
GenerateSmartDefaults = false, 
IgnoreAnsiNulls = false, 
IgnoreAuthorizer = false,
IgnoreColumnCollation = false, 
IgnoreComments = false, 
IgnoreCryptographicProviderFilePath = true, 
IgnoreDdlTriggerOrder = false, 
IgnoreDdlTriggerState = false, 
IgnoreDefaultSchema = false, 
IgnoreFileAndLogFilePath = true, 
IgnoreDmlTriggerOrder = false, 
IgnoreDmlTriggerState = false, 
IgnoreExtendedProperties = false, 
IgnoreFileSize = true, 
IgnoreFilegroupPlacement = true, 
IgnoreFillFactor = true, 
IgnoreFullTextCatalogFilePath = true, 
IgnoreIdentitySeed = false, 
IgnoreIncrement = false, 
IgnoreIndexOptions = false, 
IgnoreIndexPadding = true, 
IgnoreKeywordCasing = true, 
IgnoreLockHintsOnIndexes = false, 
IgnoreNotForReplication = false, 
IgnoreObjectPlacementOnPartitionScheme = true,
IgnorePartitionSchemes = false, 
IgnoreQuotedIdentifiers = false, 
IgnoreRouteLifetime = true, 
IgnoreSemicolonBetweenStatements = true, 
IgnoreTableOptions = false, 
IgnoreWhitespace = true, 
IgnoreWithNocheckOnCheckConstraints = false, 
IgnoreWithNocheckOnForeignKeys = false, 
IncludeCompositeObjects = false, 
IncludeTransactionalScripts = false, 
NoAlterStatementsToChangeClrTypes = false, 
PopulateFilesOnFileGroups = false, 
RunDeploymentPlanExecutors = false, 
ScriptDatabaseCollation = false, 
ScriptDatabaseCompatibility = false, 
ScriptDatabaseOptions = true, 
ScriptDeployStateChecks = true, 
ScriptFileSize = false, 
ScriptNewConstraintValidation = true, 
ScriptRefreshModule = true, 
TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings = true, 
UnmodifiableObjectWarnings = false, 
VerifyCollationCompatibility = true, 
IgnoreColumnOrder = true,
}
```

How can I prevent these `ALTER DATABASE` statements from being created when issuing the Extract() and/or how can I prevent them from being executed when issuing the Deploy()?

As a workaround, I thought about using a `Contributor` ([example contributors](https://github.com/microsoft/DACExtensions/tree/master/Samples/Contributors))  to identify any `ALTER DATABASE` and prevent it from running.

The problem is, I couldn't make the application to see the `contributor`, which is a class in the same csproj.

Perhaps contributors only work when using `SqlPackage.exe` and the DLL where the contributor is defined is placed in a specific location outside the application's \bin folder.
Is this true?
Or there is a way to make a contributor work in my case (web app which can only see DLLs in its \bin folder).

Comment: The database should have two sets of credential. One for normal uses and the other for Admin. Normal users should not be allowed to perform an Alter.

Comment: @jdweng, regarding this problem, it doesn't matter if it is a regular user or even `sa` . The behavior and problem is the same.

Comment: What’s the script produce if you select script action

Comment: @SimonSabin, select script action? what/where/how?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the script for a specific deploy/publish action, either:

- take the shortcut with SqlPackage /a:Script
- use DacServices.GenerateCreateScript

Comment: I'm not using (and cannot use) SqlPackage

Comment: DacServices.GenerateCreateScript creates a script with the same problem, and even worse, it cannot run because it scripts items in the wrong order and applying it fail with dependency errors. Besides, Extract() and Deploy() were working fine since a long time ago and I haven't read anywhere they shouldn't be utilized.